# Initialize combobox with php code based on variable

Tags: php, html, combobox

So I have this guy:

```html
<!-- Combobox -->
  <table>
  <br>Is your kitten active or lethargic?:
      <select name="Activity">
       <option value="Active">Active</option>
       <option value="Lethargic">Lethargic</option>
      </select>
  </table>
```

With two options, now somewhere above is a guy that does this:

```html
$Activity = $_POST['Activity'];
```

For my radiobuttons I have a code that checks them based on who was inside a variable before I want to adapt it to do something similar on this combobox, can anyone help out? I am a beginner in php so dumb it down to 5 year old, even add dinosaurs into the mix if you want. But do help me comprehend it.

Oh and if its not too much to ask how can default the radiobuttons to male if the variable is empty or does not have the correct word its checking for?

My radiobutton code:

```html
<!-- Radio Buttons -->
    Gender:
    <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Male" <?php echo ($Gender=='Male')?'checked':'' ?>>Male &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="Female" <?php echo ($Gender=='Female')?'checked':'' ?>>Female &nbsp; &nbsp;
```

Comment: Are you looking for just a way to mark an option as selected?  If that's what you're looking for, on the <option> you just need to add the "selected" attribute, same as "checked" but for select boxes

Answer (score 3):

You can use [selected attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) on your option tag.

```
<option value="Active" <?php echo ($Activity =='Active')?'selected':'' ?> >Active</option>
<option value="Lethargic" <?php echo ($Activity =='Lethargic')?'selected':'' ?>>Lethargic</option>
```

Comment: This is correct, disappointed in the lack of dinosaurs though, but thank you. any ideas on how to have a default selected? for this and radiobuttons?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, it works just the same as with radio buttons, except that you use `selected` instead of `checked`:

```
<!-- Combobox -->
<table>
<br>Is your kitten active or lethargic?:
    <select name="Activity">
        <option value="Active"<?php echo ($Activity == 'Active') ? ' selected' : ''; ?>>Active</option>
        <option value="Lethargic"<?php echo ($Activity == 'Lethargic') ? ' selected' : '' ?>>Lethargic</option>
    </select>
</table>
```

And to answer your second question about defaulting to male I would suggest something like this:

```
$Gender = isset($_GET['Gender']) ? $_GET['Gender'] : '';
if ( ! in_array($Gender, array('Male', 'Female')) {
  $Gender = 'Male';
}
```

This checks if `$Gender` is `'Male'` or `'Female'` and if neither is true it sets `$Gender` to `'Male'`.

Comment: What if $Gender is empty?

Comment: Alright, this might give you a PHP 'Notice'. To be correct use `$Gender = isset($_GET['Gender']) ? $_GET['Gender'] : ''`. I'll update the answer.